# How can an RSA key be placed in a "non-folder"?

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-squeeze, rsa

I lack a lot of knowledge regarding the subject so please excuse me if my question is very ignorant.

I just started out with RSA key authentication to my test-server. It did not work at the beginning and I tried and tried and re-tried to no avail.

Then I realised, I was creating "mkdir ~/.ssh" and then "mkdir ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" before placing the id_rsa.pub into the latter folder, which did not work.

My question is:

How can id_rsa.pub be placed in "authorized_keys", which is not created by "mkdir" therefore not a folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `authorized_keys` is a file. You create it by appending each individual key on a new line.